# Chrome don't want to display CSS block

Tags: css, google-chrome, html

**Hey all, i have a little problem, chrome don't want to display div block.**

For firefox, for opera and even for IE it works good, for chrome - no. Where can be the problem?

**CSS**

```
div#content div.ad_box{
float: left;
width: 247px;
height: auto;
border-radius: 4px;
background: #646d6e;
```

}

**HTML**

```
<div class="ad_box">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <img src="style/style_images/ad_2.jpg" alt="AD1" />
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? What are you expecting to happen that's not happening?

Comment: That block is invisible on chrome. In source you can see that it is there, but it is not displaying on the web. For other browses i can see it.

Comment: Do you have a link to the page I can view or a jsfiddle?

Comment: yes, sure. http://lab.gio.lt/ look at the bottom of left side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by the class name, my guess is that it's being blocked by the AdBlock extension (or something similar). This is a frequent Chrome *problem* on StackOverflow.

Disable the advert-blocking extension and reload the page and it should now be displaying.

Comment: yes, thanks, this is becouse the div's name is ad_box and chrome blocking it, very very thanksful for that

Comment: @Arnas If you're happy with James recommendation why don't you accept it?

Comment: i couldn't do it, it says:you have to wait 5 min or something like that