# My element or background isn't displaying in Chrome but displays in all other browsers, why?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, adblock

I have an element or image which isn't displaying properly in Chrome, but it displays as it should in all other browsers. What is causing this?

---

**Note:** Due to their nature, these questions are often too localized to be marked as duplicates. I've added this question as a way of targeting all of these questions purely for this reason.

A couple of examples of such questions asked in the last week alone are:

[Chrome don't want to display CSS block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635252/chrome-dont-want-to-display-css-block)

[Background image not displaying in chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550560/background-image-not-displaying-in-chrome-browser)

Comment: He's making it more googlable

Comment: This could apply to any browser with adblock, this question and its answer are big assumptions and could send someone down the wrong path.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough every question I've seen so far with a "displays in all browsers apart from Chrome" is caused by the AdBlock extension. This can indeed apply to other browsers with similar extensions, but I made this purely for the [tag:google-chrome] tag.

Comment: Good, point and noted. If you can edit your answer, i'll remove the downvote

Comment: @RyanMcDonough there we go!

Comment: Would you be able to add more to this question? Some example code with a commonly blocked ID and image size.  I'd also like to see another troubleshooting step - like "disable extensions in Chrome" included. As it stands, the question is a little bare of content.

Comment: @KatieK I thought I had already linked to the list, seems I haven't! Good call. The default blocked content list is available at https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt, I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I think that the **question** is a little bare on content, though. At first blush, it sounds like a "not enough information" question. I get what you're doing - creating a canonical question for this issue; but I think that it would help to differentiate this from similar-seeming issues which are caused by something else.  Maybe "works fine on another Chrome" or "When inspected, element is present in the DOM but has display:none;".

Comment: Just passing by fixing tags for stuff and noticed the discussion here - I agree it helps to have some context in order for a question, even a canonical one, to stand on its own, but I can see how that *might* be harmful to searchability. Might be one for meta if we were so inclined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a question which frequently pops here on StackOverflow.

The "*problem*" here is often **[AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=en)**; a Chrome extension which filters out potentially unwanted adverts from a page. If your element has a property which is detected by AdBlock ([long list](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt)) it will silently have its `display` set to `none`.

**Detected `class` example:**

```
<div class="ad_box">
    <!-- Anything within this divider will not be displayed -->
</div>
```

**Detected image `src` example:**

```
<img src="../300x250/1_512648b566578.png" alt="This doesn't display either!" />
```

(This applies to CSS `background` images as well!)

**How can I prevent this from happening in order to test it on my website?**

There are a several ways to *fix* this *problem*, but the easiest methods would be:

1. *Pause* the extension, or prevent it from running on that specific page *or* your domain by left clicking on the icon in the top right corner (default position) of your screen and selecting the required option:

   [image: Example 1: Pausing, or preventing AdBlock from running]
2. Alternatively you could *disable* the extension by navigating to `chrome://extensions/` (in your URL bar) and unchecking "Enable":
   [image: Example 2: Disabling AdBlock]

---

### Update

A couple of months ago the AdBlock extension was updated to display how many ads have been blocked on a page within the extension's icon. Provided the icon is set to visible, you can now easily see how many different content sections have been blocked by the extension:

[image: AdBlock Update Screenshot]

Comment: Why is the detected src in img blocked?

Comment: @AndyHayden Because 300x250 is a common ad-banner size. When an Img-URL contains that in its name then it is most probably an ad-banner.