# div disappears in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, markup

I can't understand, what is my problem. I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="ad-wrapper" >
    <div id="ad-left-wrapper" >
        <img src="Images/promo-left.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="ad-middle-wrapper" >
        <img src="Images/promo-middle.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="ad-right-wrapper" >
        <img src="Images/promo-right.png" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS for it:

```
#ad-wrapper
{
    height: 450px;
    width: 900px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#ad-left-wrapper
{
    width: 210px;
    height: 450px;
    float: left;
}

/* for middle and right blocks styles are similar*/
```

And this blocks are disappears in Google Chrome. What's happened?

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know. I did a quick fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/kxEnv/ ) and everything works fine on Chrome, on my side. I placed boring background-color stylings so I can see some result.

Comment: you could put the link to your page? or put it in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/6TMWn/

Comment: possible duplicate of [My element or background isn't displaying in Chrome but displays in all other browsers, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636224/my-element-or-background-isnt-displaying-in-chrome-but-displays-in-all-other-br)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the adBlock chrome extension ;) rename your id's

Comment: This sounds like a proper answer actually, that's the only thing I could see as a cause for this specific problem...

Comment: Disabling adblock for the page would also work ... obviously.

Comment: Oh my... Yes, you're right))) Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML script is working fine. This is not displaying in FireFox and Chrome because you have not mention any border color or background color.

I have tested on Chrome. Just look into it

```
<div id="ad-wrapper" >
        <div id="ad-left-wrapper" >
            <img src="Images/promo-left.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id="ad-middle-wrapper" >
            <img src="Images/promo-middle.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id="ad-right-wrapper" >
            <img src="Images/promo-right.png" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>

#ad-wrapper
{
    height: 450px;
    width: 900px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border:solid 1px; <!-- Border pixel -->
    border-color:#ff0;<!-- Border color-->

}

#ad-left-wrapper
{
    width: 210px;
    height: 450px;
    float: left;
    border:solid 1px; <!-- Border pixel -->
    border-color:#999;<!-- Border color-->
}

/* for middle and right blocks styles are similar*/
```